# Sudden 403 Forbidden error when accessing my app from browser

Tags: iis

I'm trying to deploy an ASP .NET4 application on an EC2 windows 2019 machine and the IIS is version 7.
When I try to access the application from the browser it works at first but then all of a sudden I start to get 403 Forbidden Error.

I have the right permissions to access the folder of the application for the IUSRS and I even changed it to everyone and I enabled the anonymous authentication in the IIS but still same error.
I'm blocked, can anyone have any idea what could it be ?

Comment: Read IIS logs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0#:~:text=The%20HTTP%20status%20code%20is%20recorded%20in%20the,the%20exact%20reason%20that%20a%20request%20is%20unsuccessful.

Comment: Nothing in the logs, it doesnt even show the 403 error which is weird

Comment: make sure you enabled the iis log for the site by using iis manager-> select  site -> logging -> click on enable from action pane [image](https://i.imgur.com/GUaTi7N.png) . then browse the site and check the log. or you could try iis failed request tracing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis. make sure you assign the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site folder. if possible share sample URL and detailed error message

Comment: It was rules defined in the WAF that blocked my requests. I've solved it thanks.